# Which is the exactly content of a Apple .p8 file?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, p8

I need the APN key to configure Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for an App. I asked this key and I've received something like this text by email:

```
auth:
key_identifier: "J54F12867G"
encryption_key: |

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
Mfsd9c8asdc8as9dca9sd8causdncnasldcnadLKNKJNkjnkjnLKJNLNLJNLNjln
jbhjkhbghvjhvfgchcHFCGHFCVyunlNunbuYByut56769706VHGVUYTVtyvytvtr
kjhbkjhbYbybUY7lkajsdnclkjnHkJHBkJHBs89098765lkjnlkjnjkhbjah788s
asda7kKJ
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But, I know that FCM requires a .p8 file. How should I do to convert that text into a .p8 file? Maybe a .p8 file is just a text file with that inside? Thanks.

Comment: It seems you got one yaml file, maybe you could try to encryption_key directrly

Comment: what do you mean with "try to encryption_key"? Would you explain me a little more? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. Given the name of yaml file is `a.yaml`, you can try to get the .p8 file through `a. encryption_key ` after reading the yaml file in your code

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I need the .p8 file to import in FCM configuration. That is the only way I see int the FCM web configuration to include the APN key there.

Comment: Just include those `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
Mfsd9c8asdc8as9dca9sd8causdncnasldcnadLKNKJNkjnkjnLKJNLNLJNLNjln
jbhjkhbghvjhvfgchcHFCGHFCVyunlNunbuYByut56769706VHGVUYTVtyvytvtr
kjhbkjhbYbybUY7lkajsdnclkjnHkJHBkJHBs89098765lkjnlkjnjkhbjah788s
asda7kKJ
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----` into one p8 file